# Why cron adds question mark after log file name

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I have created cron task using crontab but I get question mark at the end of log file name.

```
*/4 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path_to_cron/queue.php > /path_to_log_file/queue.txt
```

Is there any way to get read of it? The created file has question mark at the end it e.g. `queue.txt?`

I have tried to change the cron editor but it doesn't help

I can't see `^M` when I do normal crontab -e but when I try `crontab -l | cat -tve` I can see after each task there is `^M$` after log file name.

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` at the end of the task Entry and See.

Comment: No doesn't work. Still the same :(

Comment: How are you editing crontab, using `crontab -e`?

Comment: yes using  `crontab -e `

Comment: Can you try `dos2unix /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` to get rid of the unwanted characters and then `*/4 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path_to_cron/queue.php > /path_to_log_file/queue.txt  2>&1` ? I'm assuming it's root's crontab.

Comment: `after each task there is ~^M$~ after log file name.` - Well when I look at my good crontabs all I see is a `$` at the line ending.  I don't think the `^M` should be their.  So remove it.

Comment: @Zoredache I can't see `^M` when I do normal `crontab -e`

Comment: @bangal I have tried that as well :( Doesn't bloody work. it's bloody pain. 2 days working on it.

Comment: Run `crontab -l | hexdump -C`. What do you see at the line endings? 0d 0a or 0a only? Apart from all that, you're always overwriting you logfile. Don't you want to append it always instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^M` you're seeing is an extra [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) from Microsoft Windows format. You can get rid of it by converting the carriage return characters from DOS to Unix format using `dos2unix` utility.

Here's an example that converts all user's crontabs:

`sudo dos2unix /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*`

Comment: Doing this I enter a big trouble. My cron was running speratly for the other user now only root user can access the cron. Is there any way to reverse it?

Comment: Whe I try `crontab -e` it says `crontab: crontabs/ubuntu: rename: Operation not permitted`

Comment: The suggested command doesn't change privileges and ownership. You can, however, restore original permissions with `sudo chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ubuntu` and ownership with `sudo chown ubuntu.crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ubuntu`